# How to find ASP.NET DataGrid current cell contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In a ASP.NET Webpage I have a DataGrid:

For simplicity assume it has 2 rows and 2 cols only.

```
A|B
C|D
```

Question is how to find on what row user has clicked.

For example if user click on row 2, I want to be able to get values of C and D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

You can use the click event hanlder of the DataGrid which has the paramter e As DataGridCommandEventArgs.

```
Sub MYGrid_Click(ByVal Src As Object, ByVal e As DataGridCommandEventArgs)
```

e contains data about the row which was clicked.

For example to find data for the 3rd cell in the clicked row you can use this:

Item.Cells(2).Text  it is a Bound Column(assuming)